# append .mp3 at end of every file in a folder

Tags: command-line, files

I have a folder with multiple files in it, and I want to append .mp3 extension at end of each file. 
is there any way to rename all these files with one command.?

Comment: Do the files already have an extenson?

Comment: @carl no file doesn't have any extension.

Comment: ya dude but i don't have much experience with command line

Comment: ?? Your question is *asking* for a command line solution.

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes, but I post above comment because they say that my question is duplicate of some question.

Comment: I read in your question: *any way to rename all these files with one command?* This might confuse the command liners :) (and me :) )

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the files don't already have any extension at all, then run this from the directory containing the files :-

```
for file in * ; do mv "$file" "$file".mp3; done
```

If you want to be extra safe, do this instead :-

```
for file in * ; do cp "$file" "$file".mp3; done
```

This will make copies of the files and add .mp3, instead of renaming them. You can always delete the originals afterwards.

Or if you want a graphical interface for mass renaming of files, then have a look at PyRenamer in the Software Centre.

Comment: is there any way to just rename instead of creating duplicates.?
and out of curiosity is it shell scripting... ?

Comment: @piyushmandovra Yes, that's what the first part of my answer does - `for file in * ; do mv "$file" "$file".mp3; done` will rename every file to file.mp3.

Answer (score 3):

> and I want to append .mp3 extension at end of each file

short command

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.mp3"; done
```

Comment: You beat Carl by a minute, but he got a better score...  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the command *rename*. It allows perl regexpes. E.g.,

```
rename 's/(.*)/$1.mp3/' *
```

Will add ".mp3" to the end of any file or directory name in the directory.

Comment: Is capturing and backsubstitution really necessary here? what about just `s/$/.mp3/`?